# Employer: access to decision date of unrestricted certificate of sponsorship

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa

The UK Visas and Immigration authority contains several [guides](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/sponsorship-information-for-employers-and-educators) in its website destined for visa sponsors.

There are in particular 12 user manuals about the sponsorship management system (SMS).

Manual 12 (Restricted certificate of sponsorship) contains a section on "How to view previously refused, withdrawn or rejected applications", but for *restricted* CoS only.

However, there is no mention about whether this exists for *unrestricted* certificates, in any of the guides.

Is there a specific reason for this asymmetry? Or is the information available, just not mentioned in the guides?

The issue is that, in a given application, can the employer obtain such information without having to ask the migrant? For instance, the migrant may be undergoing appeal/administrative review, but if the employer sees "REFUSED" in their system, they might want to cancel/withdraw the sponsorship/job offer, negatively affecting the migrant.